# How to Query for HeartRates in HealthKit to get both traditional HKQuantitySamples as well as Cumulative Quantity Samples?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hksamplequery, applehealth

My heart rate query below uses the older traditional `HKSampleQuery` to get heart rates, however, if an app saves Heart Rates into Apple Health as a `HKCumulativeQuantitySample` then my query below doesn't capture all of the heart rates inside the `HKCumulativeQuantitySample`.  How can I query so that I capture both types of heart rate samples in Apple Health?

```
 class func getHeartRateSamplesFrom(workout: HKWorkout, handler: @escaping ([HKQuantitySample]?, WorkoutManagerError?) -> Void) {
        
        guard let heartRateType:HKQuantityType   = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate) else { return }
        
        //predicate
        let startDate = workout.startDate
        let endDate = workout.endDate
        
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)
        
        //descriptor
        let sortDescriptors = [
            NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false) 
        ]
        let heartRateQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heartRateType,
                                           predicate: predicate,
                                           limit: (HKObjectQueryNoLimit),
                                           sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors)
        { (query:HKSampleQuery, results:[HKSample]?, error:Error?) -> Void in
            
            guard error == nil else { print("get heart rate error"); return }
            
            guard let unwrappedResults = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else { print("get heart rate error"); return}
            handler(unwrappedResults, nil)
            
            
        }
        HealthStoreSingleton.sharedInstance.healthStore.execute(heartRateQuery)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your usage of `HKSampleQuery` with `HKQuantitySeriesSampleQuery`. That will get you all of the values matching your predicate, regardless of whether they're part of a series.

This is usable for all quantity types, so if you're ever querying for individual values of an `HKQuantityType`, you'll generally want to go with this query first.

Comment: Thanks but can you point me to any sample code for how to form a`HKQuantitySeriesSampleQuery` the documentation for it isn't really that helpful or provides any samples, also couldn't find anything online searching for it.